# Is there any system monitor application for debian-based systems that displays resource consumption by application instead of process?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, system-monitor

I use Linux Mint. The system monitor shows list of processes and their CPU/Memory consumption, but they're not grouped by application so I don't have any way of telling how much memory is being used by say Firefox/Chrome or Docker.

Any tools that do this?

Comment: GUI or CLI or doesn't matter? Also, you got "debian-based" in title, Linux Mint in the question body and Ubuntu in the tags. Be more accurate, please.

Answer (score 0):

You could use command-line tool [`htop`](https://htop.dev/) and switch to the tree-based view (hit F5 key).

`htop` is also in the `htop` package, see `apt show htop` (when installed)